# Specific network seems disabled

Tags: networking, wifi

I want to connect to the Office-WORK wifi but for some reason it seems disabled for some reason. Why does this happen and how can I connect to this network? I have no personal access to the router.

It is possible to connect to the network from a pc but the pi doesn't seem to allow it.

[image]

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, couldn't find it. The answer solved my problem.

Comment: @Ivaro18 You should be able to click 'That solved my problem' in the banner that pops up if you want; this will mark it as a duplicate automatically and resolve your question.